# Show Cancer Specific Survival at exact time (Kaplan Meier in Lifelines)

Tags: python, statistics, survival-analysis, survival, lifelines

```
kmf.survival_function_ (LifeLines Package)
```

shows me Cancer Specific Survival (CSS) of my cohort at different times (0, 4, 6...128 month). How can CSS be shown at exactly 120 month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `survival_function_at_times()` method will get you that value. Here is an example with a sample dataset:

```
from lifelines import KaplanMeierFitter

from lifelines.datasets import load_waltons
data = load_waltons()

T = data['T']
E = data['E']

kmf = KaplanMeierFitter().fit(T, E, label='KaplanMeierFitter')

timeline = [10, 12, 14]  # insert 120 and/or any other values here

# directly compute the survival function, returning a pandas Series
kmf.survival_function_at_times(timeline)

# 10    0.96921
# 12    0.96921
# 14    0.95069
# Name: KaplanMeierFitter, dtype: float64
```